# get first value in hash within hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a simple way, instead of looping my entire array to fetch the first value of every inner array.

so in essence I have the following;

```
array = [['test', 'test2'...], ['test' ....]]
```

so I want to grab array[#][0] and store the unqiue values.

## EDIT

Is there a similar way to use the transpose method for arrays with Hash?

I essentially want to do the same thing
Hash = {1=> {1=> 'test', .....}, 2=> {1=> 'test',....}

so at the end I want to have something like new hash variable and leave my existing hash within hash alone....  = {1 => 'test', 2=> 'test2'}

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I fully understand the question, but if you have a 2 dimensional array (array in array), and you want to turn that into an array of the first element of the second dimension, you can use the map function

```
firsts = array.map {|array2| array2.first}
```

The way map works is that it turns one collection into a second collection by applying a function you provide (the block) to each element.

Comment: or the shorter `array.map(&:first)`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really feel like explaining Symbol#to_proc though

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
array.transpose[0]
```

Comment: This would be my best guess as well, but will only work if the array contains arrays of equal size

Comment: Yes, the arrays will always be equal size, let me try this out; I knew there was a method that basically did this already, juts couldnt find it at the top of my head :)

Comment: Actually is there a similar way to do this with Hashes instead Hashes?